# How to prevent Windows 10 from booting from old drive after cloning to new drive?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning

I got a larger SSD and used a Windows 10 recovery sort of feature to clone everything (literally everything) from my old 500GB C drive to a new 1TB one. The problem is, when I have both the old and the new drive plugged in at the same time, Windows will keep booting from the old one. Booting from the new one works fine if the old one is not connected. How do I get Windows to boot from the new drive when both are connected? I'd like to format the old one and use it as storage.

If I open the Disk Management tool, I can see the drives with "EFI System Partition," which apparently contains information for booting.
[Screenshot of Disk Management tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgqiA.png)

You can see that my new 1TB drive is offline "because it has a signature collision with another disk that is online." I have been told that I can delete the EFI System Partition of the old drive (the one Windows is running on when I have both drives connected), then when I reboot, since the EFI partition of the old drive is gone, Windows will boot from the new drive. Can I get a confirmation on this, or any other solutions? I have tried some boot options from the BIOS but no luck there.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go. Remove the EFI partition and reboot. Another option is to buy a harddisk USB connector, hook it up, but keep it turned off, then when in windows, turn it on and delete all partitions from there.

Comment: @LPChip I only just tried this now, but when I select the disk and partition in diskpart, I get a "Virtual Disk Service error: Delete is not allowed on the current boot, system, pageFile, crashdump, or hibernation volume." From what I've gathered, this is because the computer is running on the same drive with the EFI partition I'm trying to delete. The issue is that it won't let me boot from the other disk when both are connected.

Comment: Then you're trying to delete the active partition, which indeed is not allowed. Make sure you select the correct disk too. So: `Diskpart` `list disk` `select disc x` `list partition`. You can even use `list volume` to ensure you get the correct disk and partition. The disks may not be in an order you would expect, so you may have been selecting the wrong disk.

Comment: Another option: get a windows install USB stick, boot from it, and at the first screen, press SHIFT-F10 to open a command prompt, and use diskpart from there. Ideally with only the old drive attached, not the new one, to ensure that you don't mess up the wrong drive.

Comment: The issue is that if the old drive is plugged in, Windows refuses to boot from the new one, but if the old one isn't connected, then I can't delete the EFI partition either. In other words, I can't boot into the new drive to delete the EFI partition of the old one.
I'll look into connecting the old drive via USB cable. I'd prefer to save the Windows install stick as a last resort since the new drive is an M2 SSD, which is a pain to physically access.

Comment: You can use the windows usb install stick and leave the new drive activated, you just have to be 100% sure that you're trying to remove the correct drive. An alternative is a linux distro, but I think the windows usb install method is actually easier.